# Backup local com acesso online

Tags: ftp, backup

Fala galera, tenho uma conta GoDaddy com armazenamento ilimitado. Queria utilizar deste armazenamento para fazer backup (fiz isso via FTP com cobian backup) mais também queria **gerenciar os arquivos via browser**. Vocês conhecem alguma aplicação que faça isso?

Desde já quero agradecer a atenção!

Comment: Qual é o ambiente do servidor? Linux? Windows? voce tem acesso shell? tem acesso root?

Comment: Ambiente do servidor godaddy é linux com Cpanel. Sim, tenho acesso shell. Sobre o root, não sei informar.

Comment: Para backup, no linux, eu usaria rsync, mas o cobian é uma boa escolha. Minha resposta abaixo não te atende?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá.

Acredito que seja algo como o [net2ftp](http://www.net2ftp.com/) que esteja buscando.

Comment: Estou testando, depois passo o feedback. Muito obrigado

Comment: Quero agradecer a ajuda, encontrei o que estava buscando, isso foi possível com as ideias passadas aqui.
Link: https://github.com/kalcaddle/KodExplorer

Answer (score 0):

Se vc tiver acesso ssh tem varias formas de fazer isso, mas ja que vc diz que tem acesso via ftp, voce pode **acessar** a partir da maioria dos browsers modernos, é só colocar o endereço ftp na barra de endereço do browser, por exemplo:

```
ftp://meuftp.com.br/
```

Voce pode ainda utilizar o [Fireftp](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/fireftp/) para, ai sim, **gerenciar** um ftp via *Firefox*, ou o [sFTP](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sftp-client/jajcoljhdglkjpfefjkgiohbhnkkmipm?hl=en-GB), através do *Chrome*.

Tem também a opção de usar um programa FTP desktop, existem vários, vou indicar o [Filizila](https://filezilla-project.org/) pq é fácil de usar e é multiplataforma.

> **Editada | Compartilhamento de dispositivos:** 
>  
>   Um boa alternativa (FREE) para backup é o crashplan, voce instala nos seus dispositivo e todos eles passam a compartilhar os arquivos que voce determinar, claro que para isso voce precisa conseguir instalar em um provedor, se pretende que os arquivos sejam armazenados nos seus discos.

[CLIQUE PARA BAIXAR O CRASHPLAN.](https://store.crashplan.com/store/)

Comment: Na verdade, a minha ideia é utilizar algo assim: http://bedrive.vebto.com/dashboard/folders/

Esse script é vendido na codecanyon

Comment: Mas para isso voce precisaria instalar o script no godady, provavelmente precisaria ser root.

Comment: Existe uma outra possibilidade gratuita para o que vc quer, vou colocar na resposta. Mas para isso vc precisa poder instalar o software em cada dispostivo.

Comment: Oi Sidon, no aguardo da sua dica.

Comment: Ja editei, é o Crashplan

Comment: Quero agradecer a ajuda, encontrei o que estava buscando, isso foi possível com as ideias passadas aqui.
Link: https://github.com/kalcaddle/KodExplorer